# How can I select a random sequence of n rows for each group in a pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, random

Suppose I have the following data frame:

```
raw_data = {
    'subject_id': ['1', '1', '1', '1', '2','2','2','2','2'],
    'first_name': ['Alex', 'Amy', 'Allen', 'Alice', 'Brian','Bob','Bill','Brenda','Brett']}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['subject_id', 'first_name'])
```

How can I select a sequence of n random rows from `df` for each `subject_id`? For example, if I want a sequence of 2 random rows for each `subject_id`, a possible output would be:

```
subject_id   first_name
1            Amy
1            Allen
2            Brenda
2            Brett
```

The post that seems most similar to this question seems to be:

[select a random sequence of rows from pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59862619/how-can-i-select-a-sequence-of-random-rows-from-a-pandas-dataframe)

However, this does not seem to take into account the grouping that I need to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little bit work after sample

```
s = df.groupby('subject_id')['subject_id'].sample(n=2)
idx = s.sort_index().drop_duplicates().index
s = df.loc[idx.union(idx+1)]
Out[53]: 
  subject_id first_name
2          1      Allen
3          1      Alice
4          2      Brian
5          2        Bob
```

Comment: This will not give a uniform probability distribution of the samples. For example, the probability of choosing the pair `Alex`, `Amy` from the first group is 1/2, but the probability of selecting the pair `Allen`, `Alice` is only 1/6. The problem is that the code randomly selects indices of two different rows in each group and then uses the smaller index to get the final sample. This smaller index is more likely to be 0 (since all other indices are bigger than 0) than 3 (since 3 will be the smaller index only if it is chosen together with 4).

Comment: Is there a solution that gives a uniform probability distribution of the samples?

Comment: @d84_n1nj4 Of course there is. I posted one such possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
import random
import pandas as pd

raw_data = {
    'subject_id': ['1', '1', '1', '1', '2','2','2','2','2'],
    'first_name': ['Alex', 'Amy', 'Allen', 'Alice', 'Brian','Bob','Bill','Brenda','Brett']}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['subject_id', 'first_name'])


def f(g):
    k = random.randrange(len(g)-1)
    return g.iloc[k:k+2]
    
sample = df.groupby('subject_id').apply(f).reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
print(sample)
```

It gives:

```
  subject_id first_name
0          1       Alex
1          1        Amy
5          2        Bob
6          2       Bill
```